# To create a product color filter with django-filter ModelMultipleChoiceFilter with color Preview(color swatches) for e-commerce web application

Tags: python, django, filter, e-commerce, django-filter

I'm honing my django skills by writing my own e-commerce web application from scratch--and I want to let users see a preview for the product colors in the color filters.

**Here is what I currently have, which works perfectly:**

[image]

**What I'm trying to achieve is this:**

[image]

My **filters.py** file:

```
import django_filters

from .models import Product,ProductColor



class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    title = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')

    price_sale = django_filters.NumberFilter()
    price_regular= django_filters.NumberFilter()
    
    release_year = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='date_added', lookup_expr='year')
    
    release_year__gt = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='date_added', lookup_expr='year__gt')
    release_year__lt = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='date_added', lookup_expr='year__lt')

    chogoyo = ProductColor.objects.all()



    def colors(request):
        
        return ProductColor.objects.all()


    product_color = django_filters.filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=colors)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['price_sale','price_regular', 'date_added','product_color']
```

Here is the **template file** where the filters are rendered:

```
        <table class="table filters_table p-0">
            <form method="get">
                <tr>

                    <tr><td class="p-0">{{ f.form.price_sale.label }}
                        <br>
                        {{ f.form.price_sale }}</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="p-0">{{ f.form.price_regular.label }}
                        <br> 
                        {{ f.form.price_regular }}</td></tr>

                    <tr><td class="p-0">{{ f.form.release_year.label }} 
                        <br>
                        {{ f.form.release_year }}</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="p-0">{{ f.form.release_year__gt.label }} 
                        <br>
                        {{ f.form.release_year__gt }}</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="p-0">{{ f.form.release_year__lt.label }} 
                        <br>
                        {{ f.form.release_year__lt }}</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="p-0">
                        {{f.form.product_color}}
                    </td>
                   <tr><td class="p-0"><input type="submit" /></td></tr>
                </tr>
                
            </form>
       </table>
```

What would be the best approach to accomplish this?
Will I need mister JavaScript for this or?..

Thank you in advance.